# 'for' loops for making groups of combination

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop

I have an array in c++ with unknown entries (minimum 6) i need a for loop (probably includes a few for loop) which makes 3 groups of 2. I don't care about order of groups or in the group. And tricky part is that double counting is not allowed. I tried something like this but it is obviously triple counts...

```
for(int i = 0; i < nArray - 1; i++)
{
  for(int j = i+1; j < nArray; j++)
  {
    for(int k = 0; k < nArray - 1; k++)
    {
      for(int l = k+1; l < nArray; l++)
      {
        for(int m = 0; m < nArray - 1; m++)
        {
          for(int n = m+1; n < nArray; n++)
          {
            if(k!=i && k!=j && l!=i && l!=j && m!=i && m!=j && n!=i && n!=j && m!=k && m!=l && n!=k && n!=l)
            {
              std::cout << array[i] << "-" << array[j] << std::endl  << array[k] << "-" << array[l] << std::endl << array[m] << "-" << array[n] << std::endl << std::endl;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: for example let our array is {1,2,3,4,5,6} which has 6 entries. Output should look like:

```
 12-34-56
 12-35-46
 12-36-45
 13-24-56
 13-25-46
 13-26-45
 14-23-56
 14-25-36
 14-26-35
 15-23-46
 15-24-36
 15-26-34
 16-23-45
 16-24-35
 16-25-34
```

But there should not be 12-43-56 or 34-12-56 since there is 12-34-56.

And for the array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

```
12-34-56
12-34-57
12-34-67
12-35-46
12-35-47
12-35-67
...
```

and so on.

Comment: Sorry I don't see exactly what you want? (since obviously you *can* write nested *for* loops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to mention I have figured out the simple detail which solves this problem:

```
for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
{
  for(int j=i+1;j<input.size();j++)
  {
    for(int k=i+1;k<input.size();k++)
    {
      for(int l=k+1;l<input.size();l++)
      {
        if(  j==k || j==l) continue;
        for(int m=k+1;m<input.size();m++)
        {
          for(int n=m+1;n<input.size();n++)
          {
            if( m==j ||  m==l || n==j  || n==l) continue;
            std::cout << input[i] << input[j] << "-" << input[k] << input[l] <<  "-" << input[m] << input[n] << std::endl;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it recursively. Choose two elements from the array to form a pair, remove them from the array and call the same function on reduced array. That way you'll have only two nested loops and you'll cover the whole array.

Alternatively, use additional array with information, which elements were already used instead of removing them from original array.

```
void GeneratePairs(std::vector<int> & values, std::vector<bool> & used, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> & results)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < values.size() && used[i])
        i++;

    if (i != values.size())
    {
        used[i] = true;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < values.size(); j++)
        {
            if (!used[j])
            {
                used[j] = true;

                std::pair<int, int> tmp(values[i], values[j]);
                results.push_back(tmp);

                GeneratePairs(values, used, results);

                results.pop_back();

                used[j] = false;
            }
        }

        used[i] = false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
        {
            printf("%d,%d", results[i].first, results[i].second);
            if (i < results.size() - 1)
                printf("-");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// (...)
int main(int argc, char * argv)
{
    std::vector<int> input;
    input.push_back(1);
    input.push_back(2);
    input.push_back(3);
    input.push_back(4);
    input.push_back(5);
    input.push_back(6);

    std::vector<bool> used;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        used.push_back(false);

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> results;

    GeneratePairs(input, used, results);

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: as well it will work for any number of elements in the array, less than 6 and more than 6 and as many as groups with pair of number will be created.

Comment: @Spook It contains many of multiple counts which I must avoid. I modified your code to be able to compile in edit2 please check whether it is my fault. In example, 6-element array should have only 15 combinations but your code gives 720.

Comment: Edit: modified the code, such that pair combinations will not repeat anymore.

Comment: It works for 6 member array but there will be longer arrays including arrays with odd number of entries and this don't work for the arrays with odd number of entries(By the way I need exactly 3 groups no matter how long the array is)

Comment: I'm sure, you'll manage to modify my example to suit your needs :)